# cant enable 3d acceleration in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, 3d

I have recently configured virtualBox 5.0.30 on an Ubuntu 16.04 server host, with phpvirtualbox as the "front end". However I am unable to enable 3D acceleration on my vm's as the check box is grayed out (see attached image). I have installed the virtual box extensions pack on the host and guest additions on the guest operating systems, hoping that it would solve the issue, however the issue persists. What would be causing this issue, and how would one go about enabling 3D acceleration?
Thanks in advance.

[image: grayed out check box]

Comment: It's not the extension pack that is necessary on the guest; it's the Virtualbox Guest Additions. That is required for 3D acceleration. Have you installed that?

Comment: I have guest additions installed on the guest and the extension pack on the host. I updated the question to reflect this.